# ROS custom msg to be used in an ESP32 microcontroller using Platformio

Tags: rosserial, ros-noetic, quaternion, rosmsg, array

I'm trying to publish an array of quaternions to a single topic on ROS noetic. For that I created a new message type following the tutorial:

```
Header header
geometry_msgs/Quaternion[] quaternions
```

After building the message, I ran `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .` inside the library folder of Platformio to create ros_lib. I also found the custom message inside ros_lib after it was created.
The following code is what I uploaded into the ESP32 and it compiled normally with no errors:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <functions.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Quaternion.h>
#include <quat_msg/QuaternionArray.h>  // Include the custom message type

ros::NodeHandle nh;

quat_msg::QuaternionArray quat_array_msg;  // Create a message of custom type

ros::Publisher quat_array_pub("quaternion_array", &quat_array_msg);  // Publish the custom message

void tcaselect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return;
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void setupThumb(){
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    uint8_t a = 4 + i;
    tcaselect(a);  
    while(!bno.begin()){
      Serial.print("Sensor ");      
      Serial.print(a);
      Serial.println(" not detected");
      delay(50);
    }
    Serial.print("Sensor ");
    Serial.print(a);
    Serial.println(" detected");
      //displaySensorDetails();
    delay(20); 
    bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);  
  }   
}

void readOutThumb(){
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    tcaselect(4 + i);    
    bno.getEvent(&event);    
    quat[6+i] = bno.getQuat();    
  }  
}

void setupFingers(){
 
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i<amountIMUs; i++){
    delay(20);
    tcaselect(i);  
    if(!bno.begin()){
      Serial.print("Sensor ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println(" not detected");
      i = -1;
    }
    else{
      Serial.print("Sensor ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println(" detected");
      //displaySensorDetails();
    }
    if(!bno2.begin()){
      Serial.print("Second sensor ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println(" not detected");
      i = -1;
    }
    else{
      Serial.print("Second Sensor ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println(" detected");
      //displaySensorDetails();
    }
    // delay(20); 
    bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);    
  }
}




void readOutIMUData(){
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    tcaselect(i);
    bno.getEvent(&event);
    quat[2 * i] = bno.getQuat();
    bno2.getEvent(&event);
    quat[2 * i + 1] = bno2.getQuat();        
  }   
  readOutThumb();
  tcaselect(7);      
  bno.getEvent(&event);    
  quat[11] = bno.getQuat();  
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize your ROS node and publishers
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(quat_array_pub);

  //Begin I^2C connection 
  Wire.begin();
  //Set I^2C data rate to the maximum possible rate
  Wire.setClock(3400000UL);
  //setCpuFrequencyMhz(240); //this didn't improve performance
  setupThumb();
  setupFingers();  
}

void loop() {
  if (millis() - lastUpdate >= 10) {
    lastUpdate = millis();
    readOutIMUData();

    // Clear the existing quaternions in the array
    quat_array_msg.quaternions_length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    geometry_msgs::Quaternion q;
    q.w = quat[i].w();
    q.x = quat[i].x();
    q.y = quat[i].y();
    q.z = quat[i].z();
    quat_array_msg.quaternions[quat_array_msg.quaternions_length++] = q;
    }


    // Publish the custom message containing the array of quaternions
    quat_array_pub.publish(&quat_array_msg);

    nh.spinOnce();
  }
}
```

The problem though is that when I try to run serial node I get this error:

> [INFO] [1698345677.484509]: Protocol version of client is unrecognized, expected Rev 1 (rosserial 0.5+)
> [ERROR] [1698345677.494124]: Mismatched protocol version in packet (b's'): lost sync or rosserial_python is from different ros release than the rosserial client

I've been trying everything for hours and just couldn't figure it out. I don't know if the problem is from rosserial, the message I created or the code i'm uploading.

Any help would be much appreciated.